# least known most fortified place for 300+ soldiers with supplies

Tags: warfare, concealment

I have a rebel group.

I have a government.

The rebels have some guns.

The government doesn't like the rebels having guns and is trying to hunt them down('cause that's just what governments do to rebels who happen to have guns).

The rebels need a hideout that is-

- in a forest/wooded area
- little known
- fortified, or easily made to be
- hard to see on satellite. If it is seen, hard to see changes brought about by rebel occupation
- accessible on foot, less so by vehicles, and preferably shielded from air attacks
- able to contain supplies and living spaces for a few hundred rebels
- near a natural water source(1 mile at most)
- has a few easily defensible entries/exits
- is not a cave. why? glad you asked.

  - easy to cave in or block entries/exits
  - confusing maze might get people lost in heat of combat
  - rather dark, and lighting means electricity, which means generators, which mean fuel, which means going into town to keep the lights on
  - way to easily besieged
  - low ceilings aren't OSHA approved
  - caves just aren't very fun to live in
- currently unoccupied
- somewhere on earth
- at least 1 mile away from any city/town and major roads
- preferably in an area that a local internet provider can hook up to internet

assume that-

- technology is the same as it is now
- the earth has the same landmarks/buildings/geological formations as it does now
- rebel base can be anywhere in the world that follows above criteria

If you know of any places that fit this, let me know so I can pass the information along to the rebels.

Comment: The stated requirements cannot be met given modern satellite capabilities such as ground penetrating radar, delayed fuse bombs etc.  Spread out your force in a forest with large mammals and they may (with great difficulty) delay detection but the moment you start fortifying it will be obvious to air/satellite recon and probably ineffective against modern aerial attack.  A large farm might be viable, urban areas might work, caves do work, but forests with internet access - no.

Comment: Would you consider a mine? They're usually built with some consideration towards layout, working room, and safety compliance (though not fun, as far as I'm aware), which might mitigate your objections to caves.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 just FYI, ground penetrating radar is not a satellite-based technology.

Comment: You chose a poor strategy for the size: 300 is far too many to gather in one location secretly, just big enough to share hunger and spread sickness without any medical or sanitation expertise, and too small to defend themselves adequately without support. Government air and artillery will massacre them in a mere few minutes while the ground forces are still far away. Successful revolutions don't usually work from a single base.

Comment: I wonder if the Internet connection isn't a deal killer? IMO a wired connection would violate "accessible on foot, less so..." (and a wire is easy to follow) and wireless connections might violate "at least 1 mile away...". Dish/satellite connections would circumvent both and might be close to untraceable without airborne triangulation.... Just wondering that it might be a deal killer if the rebels want to stay hidden.

Comment: @JBH, internet is completely optional.

Comment: I also wonder if modern thermal imaging and drones make this kind of hiding out in the wilderness almost impossible. "Campfires among a heard of 300 deer, sir? I'm kinda doubting the "deer" part..." Almost all equipment generates detectable heat. I'm beginning to realize there's a reason a lot of insurgents (like Al-Qaeda) hide in communities (aka, inside of cities). You're kinda stuck with deep underground or inside of cities.

Comment: VTC as unclear what you are asking. In particular, what does "fortified" mean? Fortified against torpedoes? Against tanks? Against light infantry? Against heavy bombers? Against cruise missiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a page from [Blindspot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blindspot_(TV_series)) and have them hole up in a disused bunker.

> - in a forest/wooded area
> - at least 1 mile away from any city/town and major roads

Many old bunkers and/or missile silos are in secluded areas.

> - little known
> - currently unoccupied

You could probably hand-wave this by saying it was built by someone that lost a war, or at least a government that no longer exists as such, and ended up forgotten. It would almost *have* to be unoccupied if it's little known, or else occupied by someone that you can take hostage (or worse, depending on how ruthless your rebels are) in order to take it over. OTOH, maybe one of your rebels is a crazy survivalist that is already occupying the bunker and offers it to his cohorts.

> - fortified, or easily made to be
> - has a few easily defensible entries/exits

Old, disused military installations are more or less by definition fortified with minimal, and defensible, accessways.

> - hard to see on satellite. If it is seen, hard to see changes brought about by rebel occupation

Bunkers are typically designed to be hard to spot, not only from the air, but often from the ground also.

> - accessible on foot, less so by vehicles, and preferably shielded from air attacks

Since they are mostly underground, bunkers offer protection from air attacks. If it's old, it may well not have any roads leading to it.

> - able to contain supplies and living spaces for a few hundred rebels

If it's large enough, no problem, especially as bunkers are usually designed to be more-or-less self-sufficient for some period of time.

> - near a natural water source(1 mile at most)

It's your world, you can easily hand-wave this.

> - is not a cave. why? glad you asked.
>
>   - confusing maze might get people lost in heat of combat
>   - low ceilings aren't OSHA approved

A bunker can be as claustrophobic or as spacious as you like. Markings for finding your way around can likewise be as helpful or as confusing as you like, and some paint can change them.

> - easy to cave in or block entries/exits
> - rather dark, and lighting means electricity, which means generators, which mean fuel, which means going into town to keep the lights on
> - way to easily besieged

Well, I can't really help with these, because they directly contradict your other requirements.

> - preferably in an area that a local internet provider can hook up to internet

This is actually dumb. If it has internet hooked up by a local ISP, that's a paper trail that can be used to find you, and might even draw attention to the fact that you're making improvements, which contradicts your other requirements. Don't do that. Use a satellite hook-up, or long-range WiFi to another site in a more urban — and therefore less conspicuous — area.

Answer (score 3):

frame challenge:
why would they want to hide in a forest? They have by far better options of actions if they stay in an urban area, especially if they can rely on the favor of part (or better the majority) of the local population.
A densely populated area with narrow alleys would make them difficult to detect, provide plenty of escape routes and Government operations costly. Further in case of civilian casualties the rebels would be able to show to the whole world how evil the Government is.
Dug in tunnels and bunkers under civilian areas are a pain to conquer if the attacker is not willing to inflict heavy casualties to the local population. Recent conflicts have shown this quite clearly.

Gathering in any other place, without civilian support (supplies, intel, human shields) is  helping the Government to wipe you out with a single strike and not getting any international blame for it.